# sending email from blackberry simulator

Tags: java-me, blackberry-simulator

what are the steps needed for sending email from a simulator ?

I am using eclipse JDE Plugin 4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure ESS Email Server Simulator.
U can download it from blackberry forum